# StackTrace at at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()

Tags: c#, winforms, citrix

I'm getting the following exception:

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()
   at IMI.Module.ControlLibrary.Forms.MDIParent.ShowForm(Form form) in
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?  It runs locally fine, but not on Citrix.

Comment: Now it says the exception is : "Cannot access a disposed object."

Comment: Can you post the code which *throws* the exception? With just the exception it's hard to help you.

Comment: Have a look at [System.ObjectDisposedException from simple form display](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1430699/1364007).

Comment: If it's a Citrix-only problem you should probably be looking at Citrix support forums.

Comment: How anybody can answer your question? There are no source code, no information about application configuration, nothing about what you already tried to solve problem... nothing. Please read SO rules before asking again.

Answer (score -1):

This was due to a button that was not being added to the form and was being disposed. I made the button invisible instead and it worked. It was not a Citrix problem.